# Magento 2 problem in running site

Tags: magento2

Site was working fine and now i m facing this issue. Please see this and help.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:256:"Warning: include(/var/www/marketplace/var/view_preprocessed/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php on line 312";i:1;s:3185:"#0 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(312): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'include(/var/ww...', '/var/www/market...', 312, Array) 

1 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(312): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page::renderPage()
2 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(245): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->renderPage()
3 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
4 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
5 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
6 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
7 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
8 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
9 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
10 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
11 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
12 /var/www/marketplace/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
13 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
14 /var/www/marketplace/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
15 /var/www/marketplace/index.php(84): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:11:"/book-store";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. remove var/cache var/view_preprocessed var/page_cache var/generation var/di
2. run 
   `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
   `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
   `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Should works.
If no, run also `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to cache folder by cd /var/cache , Then use rm -rf *

So it should delete all the files & folder inside the cache folder,
Follow the same for rest of the folders and follow the second setup which mention above.